# How to put the value in order on the label in array?

Tags: swift

I have six textView and they are in array.

And it has six values of String data type.

I would like to put string in each textView unless the value of string is "0".

Android works well.

```
        num1 = "1";
        num2 = "2";
        num3 = "3";
        num4 = "0";
        num5 = "5";
        num6 = "6";

        textViews = new TextView[] {textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5, textView6};

        if(num1 != "0") {
            list.add(num1);
        }

        if(num2 != "0") {
            list.add(num2);
        }

        if(num3 != "0") {
            list.add(num3);
        }

        if(num4 != "0") {
            list.add(num4);
        }

        if(num5 != "0") {
            list.add(num5);
        }

        if(num6 != "0") {
            list.add(num6);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            textViews[i].setText((CharSequence) list.get(i));
        }
```

[image]

And I want to implement this in iOS as well.

So in Xcode, I wrote it like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText6: UILabel!
    
    var lblArray = [UILabel]()
    var list = [String]()
    
    var num1 = "1"
    var num2 = "2"
    var num3 = "3"
    var num4 = "0"
    var num5 = "5"
    var num6 = "6"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        lblArray = [lblText1, lblText2, lblText3, lblText4, lblText5, lblText6]
        
        if(num1 != "0") {
            list.append(num1)
        }
        
        if(num2 != "0") {
            list.append(num2)
        }
        
        if(num3 != "0") {
            list.append(num3)
        }
        
        if(num4 != "0") {
            list.append(num4)
        }
        
        if(num5 != "0") {
            list.append(num5)
        }
        
        if(num6 != "0") {
            list.append(num6)
        }
        
        for i in list {
            lblArray[i].text = i
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this would work, But there was an error here.

```
lblArray[i].text = i
```

In iOS, How to put the value in order on the label in array?

Comment: *I thought this would work, But there was an error here.* What error?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an `Array` element using a `String` index. That's the reason it is giving error. Use `Int` index instead, i.e.

```
for (index, value) in list.enumerated() {
    lblArray[index].text = value
}
```

Try using `IBOutletCollection` instead. You can reduce your code to,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var lblArray: [UILabel]!
    var numArr = ["1", "2", "3", "0", "5", "6"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let list = numArr.filter { $0 != "0" }
        for (index, value) in list.enumerated() {
            lblArray[index].text = value
        }
    }
}
```